# Splitting DITA (CALS) tables with XSLT - identity transform

Tags: xml, xslt, split, html-table, dita

I have a major problem based on a Framemaker bug, for which I tried to build a workaround.
In a document we have lots of tables that I have to split column-wise.
The tables contain an attribute in the  element with which they can be identified.
So here's what I need:

Input:

```
<table attributes*>
  <tgroup attributes* outputclass="identifier">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" attributes*/>
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" attributes*/>
    <tbody>
      <row attributes*>
        <entry colname="1">sometext</entry>
        <entry colname="2">moretext</entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<table attributes*>
  <tgroup attributes* outputclass="identifier1">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" attributes*/>
    <tbody>
      <row attributes*>
        <entry colname="1">sometext</entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>

<table attributes*>
  <tgroup attributes* outputclass="identifier2">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" attributes*/>
    <tbody>
      <row attributes*>
        <entry colname="1">moretext</entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

I'm close to giving up, as everything I have tried so far hasn't worked out :(

Comment: You've provided an example, but you haven't explained it.  I don't think "split columnwise" means anything on its own without further explanation.  Why is there no `<colspec colnum="2">` in the output?  Because it's not needed?  Why did one table become two tables?  What was the criterion for determining that?  Is your objective to make a series of tables with exactly one row and one entry in that row?  What should happen if there are two rows in one of the source tables? Will there be multiple source tables in one XML document, or just one?

Comment: And why, in the source document, does a row have two entries with the same colname?  Wouldn't separate entries in a row belong to different columns?

Comment: Fixed the typo with the colnames, good spot :)

Comment: Problem is that I have to split a 2 column table into two tables with 1 column each. I ran into a bug in Framemaker 11 where my layout gets destroyed by some internal transformation of my source XML. The table originally spans over a margin column, which Framemaker now destroys, rescaling the whole table to fit in the text column. To solve the issue (for now) I want to split the table, put the side head into the first one and the paragraphs into the second one.

Comment: Ok, but the output still has colnum 1 and colname 1 in both tables.  Is that a typo too?  And if there are multiple rows, should both tables have the same number of rows?

Comment: The output should be that way. colnum refers on the roundtrip back to framemaker to a specific attribute in framemaker telling it how many columns are in that table.
So, the result should be 2 tables with 1 row/1 column each.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding correctly, all `rownum`s and `rowname`s in the output should have the value `1`.  Is that correct?  I've now asked you twice what should be done **if** the input table has multiple rows and you haven't answered me, but please try the example below.

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="colspec">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../.." mode="copyTable">
      <xsl:with-param name="colSpec" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copyTable">
    <xsl:param name="colSpec" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="copyTable">
        <xsl:with-param name="colSpec" select="$colSpec" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tgroup/@outputclass" mode="copyTable">
    <xsl:param name="colSpec" />
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $colSpec/@colname)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="colspec" mode="copyTable">
    <xsl:param name="colSpec" />
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($colSpec)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copyTable">
          <xsl:with-param name="colSpec" select="$colSpec" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@colnum | @colname" mode="copyTable">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="copyTable">
    <xsl:param name="colSpec" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copyTable"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[@colname = $colSpec/@colname]" 
                           mode="copyTable"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given this input:

```
<table a="1" b="2">
  <tgroup c="3" d="4" outputclass="identifier">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" e="5" f="2"/>
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2" e="2" f="1"/>
    <tbody>
      <row g="1" h="2">
        <entry colname="1">sometext</entry>
        <entry colname="2">moretext</entry>
      </row>
      <row g="1" h="2">
        <entry colname="1">somemoretext</entry>
        <entry colname="2">moremoretext</entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

Produces this output:

```
<table a="1" b="2">
  <tgroup c="3" d="4" outputclass="identifier1">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" e="5" f="2" />

    <tbody>
      <row g="1" h="2"><entry colname="1">sometext</entry></row>
      <row g="1" h="2"><entry colname="1">somemoretext</entry></row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
<table a="1" b="2">
  <tgroup c="3" d="4" outputclass="identifier2">

    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" e="2" f="1" />
    <tbody>
      <row g="1" h="2"><entry colname="1">moretext</entry></row>
      <row g="1" h="2"><entry colname="1">moremoretext</entry></row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

Which, as it is, isn't valid XML (because it has more than one root), but I believe it matches what you requested.